# Is the product of two Banach algebras given by the injective cross-norm itself a Banach algebra?

Tags: banach-spaces, tensor-products, banach-algebras, norms

I understand that you can take the tensor product of Banach spaces in many different ways by specifying different norms; of particular interest to me are the cross-norms. The projective and injective norms are respectively the largest and smallest cross-norms. The projective tensor product of two Banach algebras is itself a Banach algebra. Is the same true for the injective tensor product of two Banach algebras? Further, is the multiplication map contractive in this case?

Comment: Reference suggestion: “Tensor products and Banach algebras” by T.K. Carne, 1978 (the easy to trace on the net).

Comment: T.K. Carne, _Tensor products and Banach algebras_, Journal of the London Mathematical Society, Volume s2-17, Issue 3, June 1978, Pages 480–488, https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-17.3.480

Comment: Please see Definiton 4.2.25 & Theorem 4.2.26 in Palmer's book https://books.google.com/books?id=3k0lKh6QY-QC&&pg=PA473

Answer (score 2):

Lamadrid shows the counterexample of the Banach property of the injective tensor norm:

- Jesús Gil de Lamadrid, *Uniform cross norms and tensor products of Banach algebras*, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. **69** (1963), 797-803 https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1963-11037-X

I wonder there is some kind of "minimal tensor products" of Banach algebra and generalized nuclearity like $C^{*}$-algebras, operator spaces or locally convex spaces; that is the equivalence of having unique tensor products and having nice approximation property.